# SQL query to return values from an Oracle Database

Tags: excel, vba, odbc, office365

I have an Excel VBA application running on Office 365.

I have a SQL query which returns some values from an Oracle Database.
The Database connection is done through ODBC which uses a TNS file to connect with the database.

There are two applications say App1 & App2 which are working in the development server which has Office 2016 installed.

When I run the same apps in the test server App1 is working while the SQL query in App2 does not return any values.
There is valid data in the test database.

Code from App1 - Working as expected in both Dev & Test

```
DSN_ID = UCase(Sheets("Params").Range("F4").Value)
User_ID = UCase(Sheets("Params").Range("F5").Value)
Password_ID = UCase(Sheets("Params").Range("F6").Value)
DB_ID = UCase(Sheets("Params").Range("F7").Value)

'Create the connection
Set cnn1 = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmdSQL = New ADODB.Command
Dim recindex As New ADODB.Recordset

cnn1.ConnectionTimeout = 5000
cnn1.CommandTimeout = 500

With cnn1
    .ConnectionString = "DSN=" & DSN_ID & ";UID=" & User_ID & _
                        ";PWD=" & Password_ID & ";DBQ=" & DB_ID & ";ASY=OFF;"
    .Open

    strSQL = "SELECT Query Here"

    Set recindex = cnn1.Execute(strSQL)
    seqRow = 0

    If Not (recindex.BOF And recindex.EOF) Then    'record(s) found
        'Do something if records are found
```

Code from App2 - Working as expected in Dev but returning empty record set in Test

```vb
DSN_ID = UCase(Sheets("Params").Range("F4").Value)
User_ID = UCase(Sheets("Params").Range("F5").Value)
Password_ID = UCase(Sheets("Params").Range("F6").Value)
DB_ID = UCase(Sheets("Params").Range("F7").Value)

'Create the connection
Set cnn1 = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmdSQL = New ADODB.Command
Dim recindex As New ADODB.Recordset
    
cnn1.ConnectionTimeout = 5000
cnn1.CommandTimeout = 500
    
With cnn1
    .ConnectionString = "DSN=" & DSN_ID & ";UID=" & User_ID & _
                        ";PWD=" & Password_ID & ";DBQ=" & DB_ID & ";ASY=OFF;"
    .Open
            
End With

strSQL = "SELECT Query Here"

Set recindex = cnn1.Execute(strSQL)   
seqRow = 0
    
If Not (recindex.BOF And recindex.EOF) Then 'record(s) found
    'Do something if records are found
```

Dev Environment has Office 2016 installed with 64 Bits of ODBC.
Test Environment has Office 365 installed with 64 Bits of ODBC.
Both Dev & Test apps are pointing to the same database.

Comment: Where/how are `controller` and `dteDetailDate` defined ? Do you have `Option Explicit` ?

Comment: I have posted the complete function. 
Yes I have Option Explicit defined.
Controller is a dropdown box on the Excel workbook & a default value is always selected.
Please note that this is working fine in the Development environment with Office 2016.
Thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete function:

```
Sub getOrderNo()

Dim DSN_ID As String
Dim User_ID As String
Dim Password_ID As String
Dim DB_ID As String
Dim found As Boolean
Dim ProcNo As String
Dim colNumber As Integer
Dim colDiff As Integer
Dim Controller As String
Dim lineNotFound As Boolean
Dim activeRows
Dim dteDetailDate As Date

lineNotFound = False

colDiff = 5
found = False

DSN_ID = UCase(Sheets("Params").Range("F4").Value)
User_ID = UCase(Sheets("Params").Range("F5").Value)
Password_ID = UCase(Sheets("Params").Range("F6").Value)
DB_ID = UCase(Sheets("Params").Range("F7").Value)

Dim curSheet As String
curSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

Sheets(curSheet).Select

'Create the connection
    Set cnn1 = New ADODB.Connection
    Set cmdSQL = New ADODB.Command
    Dim recindex As New ADODB.Recordset
    
    cnn1.ConnectionTimeout = 5000
    cnn1.CommandTimeout = 500
    
    With cnn1
            .ConnectionString = "DSN=" & DSN_ID & ";UID=" & User_ID & _
                 ";PWD=" & Password_ID & ";DBQ=" & DB_ID & ";ASY=OFF;"
            .Open
            
    End With
    
    Controller = Sheets("Planning1").Range("D5").Value
    
    dteDetailDate = Sheets("detail").Range("I" & CalculateNewCell(11)).Value
              
    strSQL = "SELECT SSI_MBF010_VIEW.WORDNO, SSI_MBF010_VIEW.PARTNO_WOR,  procno_wor || '_' || PROCVER_WOR as procno_wor, SSI_MBF010_VIEW.PRLINE,           (SSI_MBF010_VIEW.WORDQTY) ForQty, (SSI_MBF010_VIEW.WORDQTYDEL), SSI_MBF010_VIEW.WORDSTART, SSI_MBF010_VIEW.WORDUE, WORDREF2 " & _
             "FROM mbg460 mbg460, SSI_MBF010_VIEW SSI_MBF010_VIEW " & _
             "WHERE SSI_MBF010_VIEW.PARTNO_WOR = mbg460.PARTNO_PTS AND ((mbg460.SALEPART='Y') AND WORDREF1 = 'WEEK' AND (SSI_MBF010_VIEW.CONTROLLER_WOR = '" & Controller & "') AND ((WORDQTY-WORDQTYDEL)>0) AND (SSI_MBF010_VIEW.PROCSTAGE_WOR='00000')  AND (TO_CHAR(WORDSTART,'D')='1')) AND WORDSTART > '" & Format(dteDetailDate - 1, "DD-MMM-YY") & "'"            
       
    Debug.Print strSQL
    
    Set recindex = cnn1.Execute(strSQL)
    
    Dim result As Variant
    result = recindex.GetRows
        
    seqRow = 0
    
    If Not (recindex.BOF And recindex.EOF) Then 'record(s) found
        recindex.MoveFirst
        colNumber = 0
        Dim ProcNo2 As String
        Do While Not recindex.EOF
            r = 0
            ProcNo = recindex("procno_wor")
           
            found = False
            Do While Not found
             If Len(Sheets("detail").Range("C" & CalculateNewCell(14)).Offset(r, 0).Value) > 0 Then
                 ProcNo2 = CStr(Left(Sheets("detail").Range("C" & CalculateNewCell(14)).Offset(r, 0).Value, Len(Sheets("detail").Range("C" & CalculateNewCell(14)).Offset(r, 0).Value) - 2))
                Else
                 ProcNo2 = ""
                End If
                
                If ProcNo2 = "" Then
                    MsgBox "Process version " & recindex("procno_wor") & " has WO that exist in Tropos but the process cannot be found in this Detail Sheet. Process has been made Historic but WO " & recindex("wordno") & " still exists in Tropos.   ", vbInformation, "Information"
                    found = True
                End If
                If ProcNo = ProcNo2 Then
                   found = True
                   reqdue = recindex("wordue")
                    
                   colNumber = 8 + ((colDiff * (reqdue - dteDetailDate) / 7))
                   ''''''KB
                      If r = 1 Then
                        Debug.Print 'here'
                    End If

                   Sheets("detail").Range("C" & CalculateNewCell(14)).Offset(r, colNumber).Value = recindex("wordno").Value
                   Sheets("detail").Range("C" & CalculateNewCell(14)).Offset(r, colNumber - 1).Value = CStr(recindex("ForQty").Value)
                    
                   If CStr(recindex("wordref2").Value) <> " " Then
                   Dim msg
                        msg = "Return Date " & CStr(recindex("wordref2").Value)
                        Call addComments(msg, "detail", "C" & CalculateNewCell(14), r, colNumber - 1)
                   End If
                   
                   Dim PRline, Desc
                   PRline = Sheets("detail").Range("E" & CalculateNewCell(14)).Offset(r, 0).Value
                   Desc = Sheets("detail").Range("B" & CalculateNewCell(14)).Offset(r, 0).Value
                                    
                End If
                r = r + 1
            Loop
            recindex.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    
    If lineNotFound Then
        MsgBox "One or more lines have no Efficiency factor. for more details check C:\LogFile\Error", vbInformation, "Information"
        lineNotFound = False
    End If
    
    Set cnn1 = Nothing
    Set recindex = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).